# Regular Expression to Check only 1st Match of Each Line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a PHP page that is reading text stored in a MYSQL database table.
The text might look something like this

```
Bob: Hi blah blah
(Bob walking around)
Fred Johnson: blah blah blah
Bob: Something something: something
```

I want to do a preg_replace to bold everything that comes before the first colon in each line.
So in this situation only the names would be bold and on that last line "Something something" would not be bold

What I have now bolds everything on each line that comes before any colon

```
$reg='(.*\w:)';
$text = preg_replace("/".$reg."/", "<b>\${1}</b>", $text);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$reg='^([^:]*:)';
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/A8mPA)

Comment: What if I want to bold the colon along with it? Besides just adding a colon in the output

Comment: @abney317: Include that inside the `(...)`

Comment: Regex that doesn't also bold the `(Bob walking around)` line: `^([^\n:]*:)`

Answer (score 0):

The `^` symbol is used to match the beginning of a line.  Prepend that to the beginning of your regex and it will assure that the match starts at the beginning of the current line :-)